# Xamarin.Auth OAuth2Authenticator Facebook NullReferenceException

Tags: xamarin, facebook-login, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I have created a function to login using Facebook.

```cs
public void Login ()
{
    var ctx = Forms.Context as MainActivity;
    var accounts = 
        new List<Account>(AccountStore.Create (ctx).FindAccountsForService (SERVICE));
    if (accounts.Count == 1) {
        GetAccount (accounts [0]);
        return;
    }

    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
        clientId: FBID,
        scope: string.Empty,
        authorizeUrl: new Uri (AUTH_URL),
        redirectUrl: new Uri (REDIRECT_URL));

    auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
        AccountStore.Create (ctx).Save (eventArgs.Account, "Facebook");
        GetAccount (eventArgs.Account);
    };
    ctx.StartActivity (auth.GetUI (ctx));
}
```

The thing is that after I enter my credentials in the FB login page, an exception is thrown before it reaches the `Completed` event.
I've downloaded the [Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth) project from GitHub trying to debug the program, but it doesn't break at the breakpoint unfortunately.

```cs
Caused by: JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator.OnRetrievedAccountProperties (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2) [0x00017] in d:\Downloads\Xamarin.Auth-master\Xamarin.Auth-master\src\Xamarin.Auth\OAuth2Authenticator.cs:373
at Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator.OnRedirectPageLoaded (System.Uri,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2) [0x00016] in d:\Downloads\Xamarin.Auth-master\Xamarin.Auth-master\src\Xamarin.Auth\OAuth2Authenticator.cs:282
at Xamarin.Auth.WebRedirectAuthenticator.OnPageEncoun...[intentionally cut off]
```

I'm struggling with this issue for a while now. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it! It was a mix of circumstances.
My debugger didn't stop at the breakpoints (don't know why).
What caused the problem was that I created an Object with the `Login` method above in an `OnCreate()` method.
Then I attached an EventHandler to an event of that Object.
The moment the Authenticator comes back from his Intent, the Context where my object was bound is gone.
It maybe is a bit vague to understand but maybe some code will clarify further.

```cs
//Not working, causes the problem
public class MyActivity {
    MyAuthenticator auth; //the object containing Login();
    public void OnCreate() {
        auth=new MyAuthenticator();
        auth.LoggedIn += blabla;
    }
    public void SomeMethod() {
        auth.Login();
    }
}
```

Solution:

```cs
//Working, own scope
public class MyActivity {
    public void OnCreate() {
        //ILB
    }
    public void SomeMethod() {
        var auth=new MyAuthenticator();
        auth.LoggedIn += blabla;
        auth.Login();
    }
}
```